# Fourier series generation in MATLAB help (for-loops are SLOW)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Fourier series generation in MATLAB help

Hello. I'm trying to create a fourier series in MATLAB. I have the fourier coefficients, and all I want to do is create an anonymous function representing my fourier approximation. HOWEVER. The way I'm currently doing it with for-loops takes a long time. I've tried Chat GPT but the vecorization techniques it suggests don't work, or I don't understand them. Could anyone offer some advice?

Here's my code (Thanks):

```
%%
coefficients = A' \ v1;

% creating fourier series
v1_approx_f = @(x1, x2) 0;
for n1 = -N:N
    for n2 = -N:N
        % xp_matrix(m,1) is xp, xp_matrix(m,2) is yp
        term = @(x1, x2) coefficients((n1 + N)*(2*N + 1) + ...
        (n2+N) + 1) .* exp(1j.*kappa.*(n1.*x1 + n2.*x2));
        v1_approx_f = @(x1, x2) v1_approx_f(x1, x2) + term(x1, x2);
    end
end
%%
```

I was expecting it to go much faster than it does now, the function calls to add a term to a fourier series takes 99.8 % of the operation time for my program, it's absurd. Maybe it's called every time I try to use the fourier series as it's recursively defined by all these terms? I don't know.

Comment: It is not the loops that are slow, it is the ridiculous idea of building up an anonymous function iteratively calling other anonymous functions. You should either just compute the function value directly, avoiding anonymous functions altogether, or create a regular function that does the  computation using loops.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean to say that the idea itself is ridiculous, but it is ridiculous in the context of MATLAB. MATLAB is not a functional programming language, and this particular construct is highly inefficient both in time and in memory. MATLAB is an imperative language, and trying to use it other ways is futile.